# Getting the last tag in ElementTree and append text

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I have some XML with the following structure:

```
       <root>
           <parent-1>
              <text>blah-1</text>
              <properties>
                 <property type="R" id="0005">text-value-A</property>
                 <property type="W" id="0003">text-value-B</property>
                 <property type="H" id="0002">text-value-C</property>
                 <property type="W" id="0008">text-value-D</property>
              </properties>
           </parent-1>
           <parent-2>
              <text>blah-2</text>
              <properties>
                 <property type="W" id="0004">text-value-A</property>
                 <property type="H" id="0087">text-value-B</property>
              </properties>
           </parent-2>
           <parent-3>
              <text>blah-3</text>
              <properties>
                 <property type="H" id="0087">text-value-C</property>
                 <property type="R" id="0008">text-value-A</property>
              </properties>
           </parent-3>
           <parent-4>
              <text>blah-4</text>
              <properties>
                 <property type="H" id="0019">text-value-C</property>
                 <property type="R" id="0060">text-value-A</property>
              </properties>
           </parent-4>
       </root>
```

Currently, I am parsing the `text-value-`s and joining them with some string `!`, but for the `text-value-X` occurring last within a *properties* level, I need to assign some other string `&`, and output something like:
`text-value-A!text-value-B!text-value-C!text-value-D&text-value-A!text-value-B&text-value-C!text-value-A`.

Since the attributes in `<property` cannot be specific to tags/have random values, something like `if(item.text == 'text-value-A') #get text-value-A of parent-3` won't work.

### ----------

I am not keeping duplicate `text-value-`s (in this case will not need `parent-4` since `text-value-`s of `parent-3` are identical) and I want to preserve order, so with `enumerate` I am doing the following:

```
alist = []
for item in root.findall('parent/properties/property'):
   alist.append(item.text)
self.alist = '!'.join([a for b,a in enumerate(alist) if a not in alist[:b]]
```

Given the desired output above, I am wondering if I need a different approach to this problem or the concept of something like the following will somehow work:

```
alist = []
for item in root.findall('parent/properties/property'):
   alist.append(item.text)
   for element in alist:
      if element in alist[-1]:
         self.alist = '&'.join([a for b,a in enumerate(alist) if a not in alist[:b]]
      if not element in alist[-1]:
         self.alist = '!'.join([a for b,a in enumerate(alist) if a not in alist[:b]]
```

Thanks

Comment: An inherent problem with this is that xml children are *not* ordered. In your sample I see that the `property` elements are ordered by the `id` attribute. Could this be used?

Comment: Good point, but this is supposed to be random, sorry - now edited.

Comment: Still not clear to me, at least. Perhaps you could show us what the output would be like for that input.

Comment: Incidentally, to reply to someone personally on SO (me, for instance) type the 'at' character to receive a menu of possible recipients.

Comment: @BillBell Given the above XML, the output should be this string: `text-value-A!text-value-B!text-value-C!text-value-D&text-value-A!text-value-B&text-value-C!text-value-A`.

Comment: Closer approximation, I think: You want to ignore a branch if all of its `property` texts are identical to the texts of another branch?

Comment: @BillBell correct, I am not currently keeping duplicate values. The problem is how to identify the last `text-value-` of a `property` and use a different separator, other than `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want.

- The xpath formula './/properties' produces a list of four elements.
- `property_texts` will contain a list of texts for each.
- The `any` predicate is used to test whether the set of texts for the current properties has been seen before. If not then these texts are added *as a list* to the collection. (It's important to use `set` logic to avoid missing duplicate sets in different orders.)

---

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('bt123.xml')
property_text_lists = []
for properties in tree.findall('.//properties'):
    property_texts = [p.text for p in properties]
    if any([set(property_texts)==set(ptl) for ptl in property_text_lists]):
        break
    property_text_lists.append(property_texts)

print ('&'.join(['!'.join(property_text_lists[i]) for i in range(len(property_text_lists))]))
```

It does produce this output.

```
text-value-A!text-value-B!text-value-C!text-value-D&text-value-A!text-value-B&text-value-C!text-value-A
```

Comment: It works. I appreciate your time and thank you for the thorough explanation.